# Pushing a file larger than 100 MB in github/bitbucket

Tags: github, repository, bitbucket

I am making a library which makes me to push files which includes a binary of 120 mb to my repository and its continuously rejective this push as it says files size above 100 mb is not acceptable. I am currently using the free account and planning to go for the paid account. So can anyone suggest me the repository to which I can connect and push file larger than 100 MB?

Comment: What is this binary file?  The typical solution to your problem is to not version the file using Git, which doesn't handle binaries well.  Instead, either don't version this binary file or use a file-based VCS such as Perforce.

Comment: I am using cocoapod and getting files from that repos. will this affect anyway?

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  Please read my comment.

Comment: I am sorry..its a iOS framework!!!

Comment: I don't think this should be versioned, so don't do it.  Luckily BitBucket rejected all your attempts to push this file, or else you would also have a messy cleanup job.

Comment: so that means I can not include that in my library!!